# Drag and drop not working on react-beautiful-dnd

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-beautiful-dnd

I have used drag and drop using react-beautiful-dnd but the drag is not working.

This is my drag function

```
  const handleDragEnd = (result) => {
if (!result.destination) return; // Return if the item was dropped outside of a droppable area

const { source, destination } = result;

// Reorder projects within the same column
if (source.droppableId === destination.droppableId) {
  setProjects((prevProjects) => {
    const reorderedProjects = Array.from(prevProjects);
    const [movedProject] = reorderedProjects.splice(source.index, 1);
    reorderedProjects.splice(destination.index, 0, movedProject);
    storeProjectsAndIssues(reorderedProjects); // Update the project order in localStorage
    return reorderedProjects;
  });
}
};
```

This is my jsx code

```
 <DragDropContext onDragEnd={handleDragEnd}>
    <div className="row">
      <h3 className="txt-lft mb-4">{projectName}</h3>
      <Droppable
        droppableId="kanban-board"
        direction="horizontal"
        type="COLUMN"
      >
        {(provided) => (
          <div className="col-4">
            <div className="txt-lft">
              {toDoProjects.map((project, index) => (
                <div key={index}>
                  <h5>
                    {project?.status} : {project?.issues.length}
                  </h5>
                </div>
              ))}
            </div>
            <div
              className="kanban-board"
              {...provided.droppableProps}
              ref={provided.innerRef}
            >
              {toDoProjects.map((project, index) => (
                <div key={project?.id} className="kanban-column card p-3">
                  <h2>
                    <button
                      className="btn btn-danger"
                      onClick={() => handleDeleteProject(project?.id)}
                    >
                      Delete board
                    </button>
                  </h2>

                  {project?.issues.map((issue, issueIndex) => (
                    <Draggable
                      key={issue.id}
                      draggableId={issue.id}
                      index={issueIndex}
                    >
                      {(provided, snapshot) => (
                        <div
                          {...provided.draggableProps}
                          {...provided.dragHandleProps}
                          ref={provided.innerRef}
                          className="kanban-card"
                          style={{
                            ...provided.draggableProps.style,
                            boxShadow: snapshot.isDragging
                              ? "0 4px 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1)"
                              : "none",
                            transform: snapshot.isDragging
                              ? "scale(1.05)"
                              : "none",
                          }}
                        >
                          {editingIssueId === issue.id ? (
                            // Render input fields in edit mode
                            <div>
                              <input
                                type="text"
                                value={editedIssueTitle}
                                onChange={(e) =>
                                  handleEditFieldChange(
                                    issue.id,
                                    "title",
                                    e.target.value
                                  )
                                }
                              />
                              <input
                                type="text"
                                value={editedIssueAssignee}
                                onChange={(e) =>
                                  handleEditFieldChange(
                                    issue.id,
                                    "assignee",
                                    e.target.value
                                  )
                                }
                              />
                              <input
                                type="text"
                                value={editedIssuePriority}
                                onChange={(e) =>
                                  handleEditFieldChange(
                                    issue.id,
                                    "priority",
                                    e.target.value
                                  )
                                }
                              />
                              {/* Add more input fields for other issue details if needed */}
                              <button
                                className="btn btn-primary"
                                onClick={() => handleSaveIssue(issue.id)}
                              >
                                Save
                              </button>
                            </div>
                          ) : (
                            // Render issue details in view mode
                            <div>
                              <h4>Issue: {issue?.title}</h4>
                              <h5>Assignee: {issue?.assignee}</h5>
                              <h5>Priority: {issue?.priority}</h5>
                              {/* Add more issue details if needed */}
                              <button
                                className="btn btn-outline-danger mr-2"
                                onClick={() =>
                                  handleDeleteCard(project.id, issue.id)
                                }
                              >
                                Delete Card
                              </button>
                              <button
                                className="btn btn-secondary m-2"
                                onClick={() =>
                                  handleEditIssue(issue.id, project.id)
                                }
                              >
                                Edit Issue
                              </button>
                            </div>
                          )}
                        </div>
                      )}
                    </Draggable>
                  ))}
                  {/* Rest of the project column content */}
                  <button
                    className="btn btn-success my-2"
                    onClick={() =>
                      handleCreateCard(
                        project?.id,
                        customTitle,
                        customAssignee,
                        customDescription,
                        customPriority
                      )
                    }
                  >
                    Create
                  </button>
                </div>
              ))}
              {provided.placeholder}
            </div>
          </div>
        )}
      </Droppable>

      <Droppable
        className="col-3"
        droppableId="kanban-board"
        direction="horizontal"
        type="COLUMN"
      >
        {(provided) => (
          <div className="col-4">
            <div className="txt-lft">
              {inProgressProjects.map((project, index) => (
                <h5>
                  {project?.status} : {project?.issues.length}
                </h5>
              ))}
            </div>
            <div
              className="kanban-board"
              {...provided.droppableProps}
              ref={provided.innerRef}
            >
              {inProgressProjects.map((project, index) => (
                <div key={project?.id} className="kanban-column card p-3">
                  <h2>
                    <button
                      className="btn btn-danger"
                      onClick={() => handleDeleteProject(project?.id)}
                    >
                      Delete board
                    </button>
                  </h2>

                  {project?.issues.map((issue, issueIndex) => (
                    <Draggable
                      key={issue.id}
                      draggableId={issue.id}
                      index={issueIndex}
                    >
                      {(provided, snapshot) => (
                        <div
                          {...provided.draggableProps}
                          {...provided.dragHandleProps}
                          ref={provided.innerRef}
                          className="kanban-card"
                          style={{
                            ...provided.draggableProps.style,
                            boxShadow: snapshot.isDragging
                              ? "0 4px 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1)"
                              : "none",
                            transform: snapshot.isDragging
                              ? "scale(1.05)"
                              : "none",
                          }}
                        >
                          {editingIssueId === issue.id ? (
                            // Render input fields in edit mode
                            <div>
                              <input
                                type="text"
                                value={editedIssueTitle}
                                onChange={(e) =>
                                  handleEditFieldChange(
                                    issue.id,
                                    "title",
                                    e.target.value
                                  )
                                }
                              />
                              <input
                                type="text"
                                value={editedIssueAssignee}
                                onChange={(e) =>
                                  handleEditFieldChange(
                                    issue.id,
                                    "assignee",
                                    e.target.value
                                  )
                                }
                              />
                              <input
                                type="text"
                                value={editedIssuePriority}
                                onChange={(e) =>
                                  handleEditFieldChange(
                                    issue.id,
                                    "priority",
                                    e.target.value
                                  )
                                }
                              />
                              {/* Add more input fields for other issue details if needed */}
                              <button
                                className="btn btn-primary"
                                onClick={() => handleSaveIssue(issue.id)}
                              >
                                Save
                              </button>
                            </div>
                          ) : (
                            // Render issue details in view mode
                            <div>
                              <h4>Issue: {issue?.title}</h4>
                              <h5>Assignee: {issue?.assignee}</h5>
                              <h5>Priority: {issue?.priority}</h5>
                              {/* Add more issue details if needed */}
                              <button
                                className="btn btn-outline-danger mr-2"
                                onClick={() =>
                                  handleDeleteCard(project.id, issue.id)
                                }
                              >
                                Delete Card
                              </button>
                              <button
                                className="btn btn-secondary m-2"
                                onClick={() =>
                                  handleEditIssue(issue.id, project.id)
                                }
                              >
                                Edit Issue
                              </button>
                            </div>
                          )}
                        </div>
                      )}
                    </Draggable>
                  ))}
                  {/* Rest of the project column content */}
                  <button
                    className="btn btn-success my-2"
                    onClick={() =>
                      handleCreateCard(
                        project?.id,
                        customTitle,
                        customAssignee,
                        customDescription,
                        customPriority
                      )
                    }
                  >
                    Create
                  </button>
                </div>
              ))}
              {provided.placeholder}
            </div>
          </div>
        )}
      </Droppable>
      <Droppable
        droppableId="col kanban-board"
        direction="horizontal"
        type="COLUMN"
      >
        {(provided) => (
          <div className="col-4">
            <div className="txt-lft">
              {completedProjects.map((project, index) => (
                <h5>
                  {project?.status} : {project?.issues.length}
                </h5>
              ))}
            </div>
            <div
              className="kanban-board"
              {...provided.droppableProps}
              ref={provided.innerRef}
            >
              {completedProjects.map((project, index) => (
                <div key={project?.id} className="kanban-column card p-3">
                  <h2>
                    <button
                      className="btn btn-danger"
                      onClick={() => handleDeleteProject(project?.id)}
                    >
                      Delete board
                    </button>
                  </h2>

                  {project?.issues.map((issue, issueIndex) => (
                    <Draggable
                      key={issue.id}
                      draggableId={issue.id}
                      index={issueIndex}
                    >
                      {(provided, snapshot) => (
                        <div
                          {...provided.draggableProps}
                          {...provided.dragHandleProps}
                          ref={provided.innerRef}
                          className="kanban-card"
                          style={{
                            ...provided.draggableProps.style,
                            boxShadow: snapshot.isDragging
                              ? "0 4px 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1)"
                              : "none",
                            transform: snapshot.isDragging
                              ? "scale(1.05)"
                              : "none",
                          }}
                        >
                          {editingIssueId === issue.id ? (
                            // Render input fields in edit mode
                            <div>
                              <input
                                type="text"
                                value={editedIssueTitle}
                                onChange={(e) =>
                                  handleEditFieldChange(
                                    issue.id,
                                    "title",
                                    e.target.value
                                  )
                                }
                              />
                              <input
                                type="text"
                                value={editedIssueAssignee}
                                onChange={(e) =>
                                  handleEditFieldChange(
                                    issue.id,
                                    "assignee",
                                    e.target.value
                                  )
                                }
                              />
                              <input
                                type="text"
                                value={editedIssuePriority}
                                onChange={(e) =>
                                  handleEditFieldChange(
                                    issue.id,
                                    "priority",
                                    e.target.value
                                  )
                                }
                              />
                              {/* Add more input fields for other issue details if needed */}
                              <button
                                className="btn btn-primary"
                                onClick={() => handleSaveIssue(issue.id)}
                              >
                                Save
                              </button>
                            </div>
                          ) : (
                            // Render issue details in view mode
                            <div>
                              <h4>Issue: {issue?.title}</h4>
                              <h5>Assignee: {issue?.assignee}</h5>
                              <h5>Priority: {issue?.priority}</h5>
                              {/* Add more issue details if needed */}
                              <button
                                className="btn btn-outline-danger mr-2"
                                onClick={() =>
                                  handleDeleteCard(project.id, issue.id)
                                }
                              >
                                Delete Card
                              </button>
                              <button
                                className="btn btn-secondary m-2"
                                onClick={() =>
                                  handleEditIssue(issue.id, project.id)
                                }
                              >
                                Edit Issue
                              </button>
                            </div>
                          )}
                        </div>
                      )}
                    </Draggable>
                  ))}
                  {/* Rest of the project column content */}
                  <button
                    className="btn btn-success my-2"
                    onClick={() =>
                      handleCreateCard(
                        project?.id,
                        customTitle,
                        customAssignee,
                        customDescription,
                        customPriority
                      )
                    }
                  >
                    Create
                  </button>
                </div>
              ))}
              {provided.placeholder}
            </div>
          </div>
        )}
      </Droppable>
    </div>
  </DragDropContext>
```

when i am performing drag i am getting console message "Unable to find draggable with id: 5affbf"

I will also provide my data structure

```
const projectsData = [
{
  id: 'project1',
  name: 'Demo App',
  status: 'To Do',
  issues: [
    {
      id: "1xmhnfb",
      title: 'Issue 1',
      assignee: 'John Doe',
      description: 'This is the first issue',
      priority: 'High',
      comments: [],
    },
    {
        id: "2yrhgn",
        title: 'To do 1',
        assignee: 'Doe',
        description: 'This is the Second issue',
        priority: 'High',
        comments: [],
      },
    // More issues...
  ],
},
{
  id: 'project2',
  name: 'Project 2',
  status: 'In Progress',
  issues: [
    {
      id: "3jlhjj",
      title: 'Issue 2',
      assignee: 'Jane Smith',
      description: 'This is the second issue',
      priority: 'Medium',
      comments: [],
    },
    {
        id: "4rgfbdn",
        title: 'testIssue 2',
        assignee: 'Smith',
        description: 'This is the test issue',
        priority: 'Medium',
        comments: [],
      },
    // More issues...
  ],
},
{
    id: 'project3',
    name: 'Project 3',
    status: 'Completed',
    issues: [
      {
        id: "5affbf",
        title: 'Issue 3',
        assignee: 'Mc Smith',
        description: 'This is the third issue',
        priority: 'Medium',
        comments: [],
      },
      {
        id: "6lghmfg",
        title: 'Issue 3',
        assignee: 'Mc Smith',
        description: 'This is the third issue',
        priority: 'Medium',
        comments: [],
      },
      // More issues...
    ],
  },
// More projects...
];
```

Any guess what is causing the drag functionality not working properly ?

Answer (score 0):

Check if your index.js file contains <React.StrictMode>. I had the same issue, and removing it solved the problem for me.